Getting ConnectionError while running elastic search using docker in django project
I want to run elasticsearch using docker. It works fine when I only add code to run elastic search in docker-compose.yml file, but I am getting:

Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError

when I update docker-compose.yml file to start server, postgresql db and elastic search.
This is the complete error log when I try to use search feature in my project:

ConnectionError at /
Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4935a81fa0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused))

Below is the code for dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file.
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/

docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: myproject
      POSTGRES_USER: myprojectuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - es
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://myprojectuser:password@db:5432/myproject

  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  es_data:

settings.py
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'http://localhost:9200'
    }
}

I tried to run only elastic search container, and it works fine. However, when I update docker-compose.yml file to start django server, pg db, and elastic search, I get the error.

By default, elasticsearch is listening only on localhost, that in your docker setup means it will not be accessible outside of the docker container. So, you need to add
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - network.host=0.0.0.0

This should make Elasticsearch available on http://es:9200/, if I read your configuration correctly it should be:
settings.py
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'http://es:9200'
    }
}


Thank you for your reply. I tried your approach but getting same error.
Also elastic search is running fine when I visit localhost:9200 .

Do you get this error on startup or when everything is already running? How do you setup your client in your web app?

As I pointed out in my answer you cannot access localhost:9200 from you web container. Because elasticsearch doesn't run in your web container it runs in es container. You need to access  'hosts': 'http://es:9200'

You're right. Your solution helped me fix this error. thank you, god bless you :)
